# Ionic 4: Issue building for device

Tags: ionic-framework, build, command-line-interface, ionic4, device

[Error when building for the device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPnjO.png)

I am getting an error when I try to build for the device(`ionic cordova run android --device`).  For some reason it is not creating `platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug/apk`. I have tried removing and adding android different versions. Also, I have tried `ionic cordova run android --no-native-run` and it loads but with a blank screen.

Comment: didi you try 'ionic cordova build android --prod'

Comment: I am not having an issue with building. It builds perfectly but I want to run It on a device and that is when it breaks.

Comment: Did u try deleting the application and running again?

Comment: I found 2 solutions, so if you have a problem with running the device feature: 1. Update CLI! 2 Remove Android (ionic cordova platform rm android) .3 Add android@6 and run ionic cordova run android --no-native-run OR add the latest android@latest and run ionic cordova run android. Those two worked for me, depending on the version of your projects!

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 solutions, so if you have a problem with running the device feature:

1. Update CLI!
2. Remove Android

> ionic cordova platform rm android

3. Add android@6 and run ionic cordova run android --no-native-run

OR

3.add the latest android@latest and run ionic cordova run android.

Those two worked for me, depending on the version of your projects!